# HTTP Status Code for Ambiguous Request

Tags: http-status-codes

In building an API, there is an endpoint that accepts an array of JSON objects to update associated values. Example:

```
{
  bubble_counts: [
    {
      walrus_id: 1,
      count: 10
    },
    {
      walrus_id: 2,
      count: 11200
    }
  ]
}
```

Now if the user submits multiple counts for a given walrus, I will reject the request (since it is ambiguous what the user wants), but am unsure of the correct response HTTP status code to use:

```
{
  bubble_counts: [
    {
      walrus_id: 1,
      count: 10
    },
    {
      walrus_id: 1,
      count: 11200
    }
  ]
}
```

422 Unprocessible Entity seems to be the catch-all, but is there a more specific code to this?

Comment: 409 is being used for versioning conflicts on the resource. A 400 is when `The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.` The request isn't invalid syntax, but semantically invalid.

Answer (score 0):

For ambigious the HTTP Status Code is 300.
For details check this out : [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=netcore-3.1#:~:text=Ambiguous%20indicates%20that%20the%20requested,is%20a%20synonym%20for%20MultipleChoices%20.&text=Equivalent%20to%20HTTP%20status%20502.)